# Как использовать больше одного шейдера в Android OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: android, opengles

Как использовать 2 типа шейдеров в одном приложении? Например первый шейдер отвечает за рисование паровоза (обычные полигоны, с учетом нормалей и текстур), а второй отвечает за дым, при этом работает с системой частиц (пиксельные спрайты). Нужно ли в таких случаях делать две шейдерные программы и переключаться через UseProgram() или надо как-то условиями в самих шейдерах делать ветки?

Comment: Можно и так и так.

Answer (score 0):

да можно, переключение между шейдерами с помощью команды `glUseProgram();`
создаешь 2 или больше шейдерных программы и перед рисованием фигуры устанавливаешь нужный шейдер.
переключатся между алгоритмами рисования в самом шейдере не надо, тормозить будет, тк проверки будут проходить для каждой вершины, а еще хуже для каждого пикселя.

Comment: @Kromster, ответ дополнился.